# Getting the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: samlRequest cannot be null or empty"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0

I'm trying to generate response redirect using "Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest" class, but when I make the redirect I'm getting this error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: samlRequest cannot be null or empty
```

I know, I've to create a `samlRequest` object, but I'm unable to find any documentation for this situation. Below is the sample code I'am using to generate the request redirection:

```java
Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest authnRequest = Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest
                    .withRelyingPartyRegistration(relyingPartyRegsitration)
                    .relayState(relayState)
                    .build();

String encodedRequest = URI.create(authnRequest.getAuthenticationRequestUri().toString()).toASCIIString();
response.sendRedirect(encodedRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting an error is because `Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest` requires you to specify the signed and serialized `samlRequest` as part of constructing it.

`Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest` is a domain object that holds the authentication request, not the thing that creates, signs, and serializes one.

The component that creates, signs, and serializes is `Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver`. When given an `HttpServletRequest`, it returns a `Saml2RedirectAuthenticationRequest`. You can read more about this in [Spring Security's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication-requests.html).

I would recommend using Spring Security's filter chain to create and send the `AuthnRequest` for you instead of formulating it directly. When you use the `saml2Login` DSL method in your `HttpSecurity` settings or when you configure Spring Boot for SAML, then this is all done for you when you redirect to `/saml2/authenticate/{registrationId}`.

You can see [Spring Security's Boot sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/login) that has SAML 2.0 Login and Logout fully configured.

Comment: Hi @jzheaux, Thanks for the reply. Some of the restrictions I have is My current application is Spring MVC based and not Springboot based. Also, the ADFS configured in such a way that AuthnRequestsSigned flag is set to false (and configured with POST binding not redirect). So, there is no need of signing AuthnRequest I believe. Also, could you please provide some alterations to SAMLProcessor.sendMessage function. FYI, the current application implemented with Spring security extensions and am trying to migrate to latest spring security library.

Comment: I was able to create the AuthnRequest object and encoded it as per the need. But, in the ADFS server I keep getting "System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data while decoding". Here I am using HTTP-Redirect. As I said in my previous comment we configured ADFS server with AuthnRequestsSigned flag as false. For using HTTP-Post bindings from backend any suggestions of alternate functions instead of SAMLProcessor.sendMessage (as it is used in the older versions of OpenSAMl library) function. Thanks in advance and for your kind help.